# Подсчёт среднего, максимального и минимального возраста в c++

Tags: c++, struct

Не понимаю в чём ошибка.

Выводит:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
struct StatisticVisitors
{
public:
    string surename[255];
};

void StatisticGy::dataRetrieval()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    StatisticVisitors persone;

    cout << "Enter the number of visitors: "; cin >> visitors; CLEAR;

    for (int i = 0; i < visitors; i++)
    {
        cout << "Persone( " <<  i + 1 << " )";
        cout << "Enter surename: "; cin >> persone.surename[i]; cout << "\n";
    }

    int *age = new int[visitors];

    for (int i = 0; i < visitors; i++)
    {
        age[i] = 0 + rand() % 66;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < visitors; i++)
    {
        cout << "\nSurename: " << persone.surename[i] << "\tAge: " << age[i] ;
    }
    cout << "\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < visitors; i++)
    {
        age[i] > maximumAge ? maximumAge = age[i] : minimumAge = age[i];

        summar += age[i];
    }
    averageAge = summar / visitors;


    cout << "\nsr: " << averageAge;
    cout << "\nold: " << maximumAge;
    cout << "\nyong: " << minimumAge << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Насчёт наименьшего возраста, он сейчас коряво считается в строке с наибольшим:

```
age[i] > maximumAge ? maximumAge = age[i] : minimumAge = age[i];
```

То есть, наименьшим считается любой не наибольший. Правильнее сделать так:

```
if (age[i] > maximumAge)
    maximumAge = age[i];
else if (age[i] < minimumAge)
    minimumAge = age[i];
```

Вторая ошибка: в коде не указаны начальные значения `maximumAge`, `minimumAge` и `summar` – а изначально там мусор, поэтому вычисления ошибочны. Запишите туда значения в начале кода метода:

```
int maximumAge = 0; // чтобы любой другой возраст был больше
int minimumAge = INT_MAX; // чтобы любой другой возраст был меньше
int summar = 0; // чтобы сумма возрастов сначала была нулевая
```

Comment: min и max нельзя присваивать нулю, иначе получится что возраст никогда меньше 0 не будет и всегда так и останется 0. max - в данной задаче еще прокатит, но в целом тоже так лучше не делать.

Comment: @user1706674 Тоже заметил, уже поправил `;)`

Comment: вижу уже исправили min :) самый правильный вариант присваивать первые значения из списка.

Comment: @user1706674 Где доказательство, что это *самый* правильный вариант? Поиск в интернете выдаёт лишь статьи о том, что инициализация константами с max/min возможными значениями даёт покрытие любых физически возможных вариантов.

Comment: ну скажем когда у вас все числа лежат в пределе меньше 0, то максимальным у вас так и останется 0. в вашем примере max должен быть тогда INT_MIN.

Comment: Конкретно в данном случае можно ограничиться у нулём т.к в рамках задачи речь идёт про возраст, который не может быть меньшим нуля. Замена на `INT_MIN` здесь ничего не улучшит. Однако это вообще ничего не говорит о том, почему же инициализация первыми значениями **самый** правильный способ `(:`

Answer (score 0):

Вы не инициализировали первоначальные значения переменных.
Решение:

```
....
summar = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < visitors; i++)
{
    if(i == 0) 
    {
        maximumAge = age[i];
        minimumAge = age[i];
    }
    if(age[i] > maximumAge)
    {
        maximumAge = age[i];
    }
    if(age[i] < minimumAge)
    {
        minimumAge = age[i];
    }
    summar += age[i];
}
....
```

Comment: Они были инициализированы в классе, просто я их здесь не отметил.